# All javascript from ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/ broken? Breaking all external refs? Since Friday?

Tags: javascript, jquery, networking

Ok, since Friday mid-evening EST from the comfort of my livingroom I have been investigating why certain websites seem to be unavailable and broken. I am a Verizon FIOS subscriber in Hudson Country NJ, for point of source reference.

What I found is fascinating so far. I am neither a networking nor javascript expert, but perhaps I know enough to shoot my own foot off with a silly post here....

I noticed first:

support.microsoft.com

technet.microsoft.com

instagram (? anecdotal from family...)

tumblr.com .... many others

Including hulu plus were failing and unable to be loaded, though other sites were working fine, mostly everything else was working fine.

What I found is ... nslookups, all good, traceroutes (partially good), and curls without recursion definitely good.

Checked Internet Pulse (and others): www.internetpulse.net
- Fri-Now, big issue Sat morning with lots of errors on L3 peering, up to 14% packet loss

Checked Digital Attack Map (and others): www.digitalattackmap.com
- Typical, I guess, not an expert there but the attack volume over time didn't seem to indicate anything special

Started Checking these sites with Chrome Dev View.... (where things got interesting):

- Main pages load, routes ok, recursion into imports/includes start
- Always fails on ajax.aspnetcdn.com includes for javascripts - Found first, ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js always fails, thought it was JQuery related.
- Then found that 1.7, and other .js's were failing
- Found connection reset was common with non https - Found curl: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to ??? where applicable.

Google referenced ajax works fine, so where I am going with this, is there a problem with anything that directly references, or indirectly:

ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/

But everything that either caches those scripts themselves or references:

ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/

Is ok at the moment?

Anyone able to confirm there is some nefarious issue with external references to the microsoft hosted scripts?

Notes:

- Javascripts are not the only thing failing, but clearly I see them as a higher % of failures than other things like images and css scripts and other compound/custom URLs which are not clear as to the internals on the backend.
- http changed to h**p throughout this submission so stack would accept it given limit of 2 links and experience points...  when everything was run of course it was http.

Output:

curl 'h**p://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js' -H 'Accept: /' -H 'Referer: h**p://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2881688' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36' --compressed curl: (56) Recv failure:

Connection reset by peer

traceroute ajax.aspnetcdn.com traceroute to cs1.wpc.v0cdn.net (93.184.215.200), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets 1 wireless_broadband_router (192.168.1.1) 1.251 ms 0.987 ms 0.996 ms 2 masked....(...) 14.071 ms 19.181 ms 6.934 ms 3 masked....(...) 11.748 ms 18.271 ms 8.143 ms 4 * * * 5 masked....(...) 12.694 ms 29.482 ms 20.443 ms 6 edgecast.com.customer.alter.net (152.193.2.10) 46.581 ms edgecast.com.customer.alter.net (152.193.2.58) 42.549 ms 24.093 ms 7 93.184.215.200 (93.184.215.200) 28.393 ms 24.488 ms 15.412 ms

Same CURL from Google (love ya)

curl 'h**p://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js' -H 'Accept: /' -H 'Referer: h**p://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2881688' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36' --compressed

/*! * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5.1 * h**p://jquery.com/ * * Copyright 2011, John Resig * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses. * h**p://jquery.org/license * * Includes Sizzle.js * h**p://sizzlejs.com/ * Copyright 2011, The Dojo Foundation * Released under the MIT, BSD, and GPL Licenses. * * Date: Wed Feb 23 13:55:29 2011 -0500 */ (function(a,b){function cg(a…(RESPONSE TRUNCATED MANUALLY BY ME FOR THIS POST….max(f.documentElement["client"+c],f.body["scroll"+c],f.documentElement["scroll"+c],f.body["offset"+c],f.documentElement["offset"+c]);if(a===b){var h=d.css(f,e),i=parseFloat(h);return d.isNaN(i)?h:i}return this.css(e,typeof a==="string"?a:a+"px")}}),a.jQuery=a.$=d})(window);

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone who is viewing this, it was the microsoft hosted site routes that were broken.  A few days later the routes were fixed and the problem was resolved.  I think this is an antipattern of the future for js.  Download and host your own dependencies or suffer from others....

Here is the reddit post I had opened of the same with the results days later:

http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/2tn8z7/all_javascript_from_httpajaxaspnetcdncomajax/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be happening again (ajax.aspnetcdn.com not reachable right now)...

[Site-check](http://www.websitedown.info/ajax.aspnetcdn.com)

I work with ASP.NET MVC6 (RC) and had problems with bootstrap (e.g. glyphicons haven't worked in the hosting environment outside of VS).
After I have changed the reference in _Layout.cshtml (unter  from external to internal, it works now:
Changed:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

So it seems as the site is down temporarily (at least from Switzerland) or has changed (not found any information on the web right now)